# What is the way to describe final exams?

Tags: translation, phrase, english-to-german

What is the way to describe final exams? If want to describe my final exams at the end of my semester at university, what's the noun for "final exams"? Between my unreliable dictionary and Google Translate, I've wrangled "Studieren für Abschlussprüfungen" to mean "Studying for Finals". Is this accurate?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, Google Translate is right. The best word for *final exams* is *Abschlussprüfung(en).*

I would rather prefer the verb *lernen* instead of *studieren* though. The expression is therefore:

> für die Abschlussprüfungen lernen.

Comment: but not only *prefer* "lernen", I think "studieren" doesn't fit well here. One would understand it, but no German would say that.